# What is this statement: (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1

Tags: java

```
   Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int temp = array[i];
            Integer count = map.get(temp);

            map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
```

Can someone help me understating of `(count == null) ? 1 : count + 1`, above? code.

Comment: That's the ternary operator. It's basically saying "if count == null, give 1. If not, give count + 1"

Comment: `?` is called the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 4):

If `count` is `null`, then put 1, otherwise put count+1.
This is a `ternary operator`.
In a longer way you can write

```
if (count == null) {
  map.put(temp, 1);
} else{
  map.put(temp, count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its called `ternary operator` because it uses three operands.

Syntax of the operator:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

And in official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

So the code

```
map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
```

could be written as:

```
if (count == null) {
    map.put(temp, 1);
} else {
    map.put(temp, count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (count == null) {
    map.put(temp, 1);
}
else {
    map.put(temp, count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that key `temp` value is null then we need to put 1 otherwise count+1.

Answer (score 0):

If count  is null then it will put 1 in map else if count is not null it will increment count value by 1 and put  that in map.